# How do I cast data into non-equi columns?

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a dataset of events, grouped by `let` like so:

```
set.seed(3)
events <- data.frame(
  let = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=3),
  age = c(0,sample(1:20, size=2),
          0,sample(1:20, size=2)),
  value = sample(1:100, size=6))

  let age value
1   A   0    61
2   A   4    60
3   A  16    13
4   B   0    29
5   B   8    56
6   B   7    99
```

How can I cast the data frame so that age is multiple columns grouped into weeks? So for each column, take the value of the largest age that is less than or equal to 0, 7, 14, 21 days.

```
events.cast <- data.frame(
  let = LETTERS[1:2],
  T0_value = c(61,29),
  T1_value = c(60,99),
  T2_value = c(60,56),
  T3_value = c(13,56))

 let T0_value T1_value T2_value T3_value
1   A       61       60       60       13
2   B       29       99       56       56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `cut` the 'age' into buckets, get the `max` row by that group and 'let', then reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
events %>%
  group_by(grp = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf,0, 7, 14, 21),
        labels = str_c("T", 0:3, "_value")), let) %>% 
  slice(which.max(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-age) %>% 
  group_by(let) %>%
  complete(grp = unique(.$grp)) %>%
  fill(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   let [2]
#  let   T0_value T1_value T2_value T3_value
#  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 A           61       60       60       13
#2 B           29       99       56       56
```

#### data

```
events <- structure(list(let = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), age = c(0L, 
4L, 16L, 0L, 8L, 7L), value = c(61L, 60L, 13L, 29L, 56L, 99L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: A's T3 value is NA and B's T4 value is NA as well. Can these NAs be listed as the previous value in time? So 60 and 56, respectively.

Comment: Is there anyway to fill in values <= max age by let, And once the age of the value is > the max age by let, list value as NA?

Comment: @EricFrey Can you please post as a new question so that it would  be more clear

Comment: submitted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429703/how-do-i-fill-data-until-last-non-missing-value