# How do I fill data until last non-missing value?

Tags: r, tidyr, fill

I have some data grouped by let like so:

```
events <- structure(list(let = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), age = c(0L, 
4L, 16L, 0L, 8L, 7L), value = c(61L, 60L, 13L, 29L, 56L, 99L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

  let age value
1   A   0    61
2   A   4    60
3   A  16    13
4   B   0    29
5   B   8    56
6   B   7    99
```

How can I cast the data frame so that:

1. Age is multiple columns grouped into weeks. So for each column, take the value of the largest age that is less than or equal to 0, 7, 14, etc. days
2. Fill in age UNTIL the last non-missing value by `let`.

End result would look like this:

```
    events.cast <- data.frame(
 let = LETTERS[1:2],
  T0_value = c(61,29),
  T1_value = c(60,99),
  T2_value = c(60,56),
  T3_value = c(13,56))

 let T0_value T1_value T2_value T3_value
1   A       61       60       60       13
2   B       29       99       56       NA
```

Note that this is coming from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397169/how-do-i-cast-data-into-non-equi-columns) I asked.

Comment: Why is 60 listed twice? Please elaborate the logic.

Comment: Do you need `events %>%
   group_by(grp = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf,0, 7, 14, 21),
         labels = str_c("T", 0:3, "_value")), let) %>% 
   slice(which.max(value)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-age) %>% 
   group_by(let) %>%
   complete(grp = unique(.$grp)) %>%
   fill(value) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(value = replace(value, n(), NA)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value)`

Comment: @tmfmnk, 60 is listed twice because the value of the largest age that is less than or equal to 14 days is 60 for A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a column of 'actuals' before the `complete` and use that to create the `NA` in 'value' column based on the occurrence of `NA` in 'actuals'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
events %>% 
    group_by(grp = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf,0, 7, 14, 21),
        labels = str_c("T", 0:3, "_value")), let) %>% 
    slice(which.max(value)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-age) %>% 
    mutate(actuals = TRUE) %>%  
    group_by(let) %>% 
    complete(grp = unique(.$grp)) %>% 
    fill(value) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(i1 = cumsum(is.na(actuals)), 
           value = replace(value, i1 == max(i1), NA)) %>%
    select(-i1, -actuals) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  let   T0_value T1_value T2_value T3_value
#  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 A           61       60       60       13
#2 B           29       99       56       NA
```